# the google scripts cannot work and say makeCopy() not a function

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function createMailMergeDocument() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form responses 1"); // Replace "Sheet1" with the name of your sheet
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = data.shift();
 
  var customerNameColumnIndex = header.indexOf("EnglishName"); // Replace "Customer Name" with the name of your customer name column
  var templateId ="1tq29zF0i2R9oV12hkOhNOIWGhe8kvp6T4EHKlM4nGxk"; // Replace "TEMPLATE_ID_HERE" with the ID of your mail merge template in Google Drive
 
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var customerName = data[i][customerNameColumnIndex];
    var folderName = customerName.replace(/\s+/g, "_"); // Replace any spaces in the customer name with underscores
    var templateDoc = DriveApp.getFilesByName('CustomerDocumentTemplate');
    var copiedDoc = templateDoc.makeCopy(folderName).setName(customerName + ".docx");
    var body = copiedDoc.getBody(); 
    body.replaceText("{{EnglishName}}", data[i][header.indexOf("EnglishName")]);
    body.replaceText("{{身份證號碼/ 護照號碼}}", data[i][header.indexOf("身份證號碼/ 護照號碼")]);
    // Perform mail merge here using the customer name and other data from the sheet
    // ...
 
    copiedDoc.saveAndClose();
  }
}
```

The above google script runs and returns
TypeError: templateDoc.makeCopy is not a function
createMailMergeDocument @ Code.gs:13

Answer (score 0):

[.getFilesByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename) returns a `File Iterator`, not a file.

You will have to add `.next()` afterwards if the file is guaranteed to be found. If not you will have to incorporate a `while` loop to search for the correct file.

Try:

```
var templateDoc = DriveApp.getFilesByName('CustomerDocumentTemplate').next()
```

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator

---

Consider also, [.getFileById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid).